# Cannot pass 2d array into a helper function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, multidimensional-array, parameters

I was learning c++ and implementing the game of life when I created a helper function to print the current board which is a 2d array. I cannot seem to pass the array into the function as I get an error, "Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char [rows][cols]' to 'char (*)[cols]' for 3rd argument." I am using Xcode as an ide if that helps.

```
void printArray(int rows, int cols, char board[rows][cols]){
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++){
            cout << board[r][c];
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main(){
     char board[5][5];
    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++){
            board[r][c] = 0;
        }
    }
    printArray(5, 5, board);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried switching up the parameter to different things such as char **board, char board[][cols], char (*board)[cols]. Even casting my input board which leads to other errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Comment: You should avoid using built-in arrays in the first place. If you used `std::vector` you would not have this problem.

Comment: @J.Doe I already tried that didn't work

Comment: @walnut yea I realize my mistake now but I thought I might as well figure this out to Rest In Peace.

Comment: The trick you're using here `void printArray(int rows, int cols, char board[rows][cols])` works in C and possibly by extension in C++, but to be fully compliant in C++ all array dimensions must be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass 2d arrays to a function there is a special syntax. Unfortunately, the other previous 2 answers do not answer fully correctly.

You can pass by reference or by pointer. The array dimensions must be compile time constants. That is a requirement from C++.

Please see:

```
constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 3;
constexpr size_t NumberOfColumns = 4;

// Typedef for easier usage
using IntMatrix2d = int[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];

//Solution 1 ------
// Pass by reference
void function1(int(&matrix)[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns])  {}

// Pass by pointer
void function2(int(*m)[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns])  {}

//Solution 2 ------
// Pass by reference
void function3(IntMatrix2d& matrix) {}

// Pass by pointer 
void function4(IntMatrix2d* matrix) {}


int main()
{
    // Solution 1
    // Handwritten matrix. Dimension is compile time constant
    int matrix1[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns];

    // Pass by reference
    function1(matrix1);

    // Pass by pointer
    function2(&matrix1);

    // Solution 2 -----
    IntMatrix2d matrix2;

    // Pass by reference
    function3(matrix2);

    // Pass by pointer
    function4(&matrix2);

    return 0;
}
```

If you typedef or use using for your type definition, then it gets rather intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are **not very comfortable with pointers** then there are some easy ways to do the task

1. You have to define the **2d array size by default**, before passing array to the function so that the size doesn't seem to be unknown to the function.

```
#include <iostream>

const std::size_t rows=5;
const std::size_t cols=5;

void printArray(char board[rows][cols]) {
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            std::cout << board[r][c];
            std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    char board[rows][cols];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            board[r][c] = '0';
        }
    }
    printArray(board);
    return 0;
}
```

2. Use **vector**. Make your board a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
void printArray(std::vector<std::vector<char>> &board) {
    for (int r = 0; r < board.size(); r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < board[0].size(); c++) {
            std::cout << board[r][c];
            std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> board(rows, std::vector<char>(cols, '0'));
    printArray(board);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this problem while doing a project for a class. To work around it, I made a double pointer array, and then used passed it to the function to manipulate it.

```
int** createArr(){

    int** pixels = 0;
    pixels = new int*[numrows];

    for (int row = 0; row < numrows; row++){
    pixels[row] = new int[numcols];

            for (int col = 0; col < numcols; col++){
                ss >> pixels[row][col];

            }
    }
    return pixels;
}

int** newArr = createArr(); //calls function to create array

func(newArr); //where func is a function that modifies the array.
```

Don't forget to delete your arrays at the end to avoid memory leaks. Hope this helps.

Comment: To complete this answer you should add the destruction logic as correctly freeing all of the memory from an array of arrays is non-trivial.

Comment: A Solution should not introduce more problems than it solves. `new[]` in user code ... really!??